# re.findall not returning full match when using 'or' operator

Tags: python

Every `()` has `?:`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'over (?:\d+\s[^\s]*?)|(?:\d+[^\s]*)', 'over 9000')
['9000']

>>> re.findall(r'over (?:\d+[^\s]*)', 'over 9000')
['over 9000']
```

Is this some kind of bug? I even tried `regex` package, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

nvm. Fixed it with another pair of parenthesis:

```
>>> re.findall(r'over (?:(?:\d+\s[^\s]*?)|(?:\d+[^\s]*))', 'over 9000')
['over 9000']
```